# Session id not working in php after login

Tags: php, session

I am having a problem of session id on the server and on localhost it working...
I am trying to get the session id of the user after the login is done but it returning another user id but same code is working fine for the localhost...

here is my code

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        include("connection.php");
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $qry = mysql_query("select * from tbl_clients where flag='enabled'");
        $qry12= mysql_query("select * from tbl_clients");
        $total=mysql_num_rows($qry12);

    }else{

        header("location:index.php");
    }

echo $id;
```

Comment: How you have set the session id ?

Comment: Could you please place the code which is set the login sessions?

Comment: its working for the localhost but if uploaded on server i am not getting the id of user which is login another id of user is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You failed to check if session id is set. You only checked for session name. Add && $_session['id'] too to make sure both exists.
TRY:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{ print $_SESSION['id'] ; }
 else { print "No session id set";  $_SESSION['id']='100'; } 
print $_SESSION['id'];
```

Tell me the result

Comment: TRY         [code]if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ print $_SESSION['id'] ; } else { print "No session id set";  $_SESSION['id']='100'; } print $_SESSION['id'];[/code]  Tell me what the result is

Answer (score 0):

The index.php should have **session_destroy();**  destroying the session to prevent the session id from occuring again. Try including your code from index.php so that we can clearly see the problem.

Comment: i am getting the session id of user for the localhost but not working if uploader on server